# Javascript not working - 2 different div containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am struggling with trying to make a link in a separate div container open a panel in a completely different div container (which if you click on the second div containers link, the panel also opens and the link itself has an active state) - I got the part down where if I click on a link in the first div container, the panel opens up from the second div container, but am struggling with making that first div containers link activate the active state in the second div container...

If you take a look at the demo, simply click on the {ÑØ§} Members tab, as the other 2 are inactive atm...Once you click on that tab, a panel opens (not the one I am talking about though), now that; that panel is open, look at the very bottom, on the left side in the div container that holds the info title: "Official Roster", there is a link in there that says "rank", if you click on that specific link, the O.F. panel opens up like it should, however, the active state selects them all rather than just the 1 that is selected...I'm getting close, but am seriously stuck and can't seem to figure it out...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Djdzw/2/

I believe it is pure javascript that would be needed, however, it could also be the css as well. I'll provide what code I have atm below, however - I'll only provide the javascript since posting all the code that is required would simply be too much...So, if you could simply take a look at the demo above, it might be easier on the eyes ;)

JAVASCRIPT:

/* ===== The section below is what needs to be edited ===== */

```
$('.info_box p a').click(function () {
    var a = $('#profile_list a');
    $('#profile_list a').removeClass('active');
    $('#profile_list a').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
$('.info_box p a').click(function () {
    var id = this.id; //get the id of the clicked item
    var a = $('#profile_list a[href="#' + id +'"]'); //construct the selector to select the menu item which has the same href
    $('#profile_list a').not(a.addClass('active')).removeClass('active'); //now do the add/remove class

});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm43L/)**

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it worked. I hope it is  what you're looking for:

```
$('.info_box p a').click(function () {
    var a = $('#profile_list a');
    $('#profile_list a').removeClass('active');
    $('#profile_list a.panel[href=' + $(this).attr('href') + ']').addClass('active');
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Djdzw/8/)

Comment: Yes it did, Thank you for sharing, however, what you posted was after the issue had been solved!  I gave you a +1 though since I already had someone else's answer selected prior to your answer given.